# Add point polyline polygon in google earth

Tags: google-maps, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I want to develop a web-application using Google Earth in the browser.

I need to add a point feature, a polyline and a  polygon.

The web-applicaton needs to display the features the same as the Google Earth desktop application.

I want to use the Google Maps Api and the Google Earth Api to deliver google earth in the browser.

How can I make this kind of application for myself, what is the best way for doing so?

Comment: -1 This question is way to vague and unspecific to be answered

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the Google Earth Api documentation. http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/reference/

Simple objects like points, polylines and polygons can be created via the api or loaded in Kml format. Take a look at the following documents.

Geometries and Overlays
http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/geometries.html

Introduction to Kml
http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/kml.html

From the sounds of it the KML approach might be the easiest thing - depending on the nature of the application. If you have some existing data in Google Earth, it would be easy to save this as a kml or kmz file and load it in to the Google Earth Api.